# program for multiplication of two polynomials using linked list

Tags: c, gcc, linked-list, algebra, polynomial-math

I am trying to multiply to polynomials using a linked list.
Here is the code but this is giving me incorrect result.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int coefficient, exponent;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *hPtr1, *hPtr2, *hPtr3;
/*
 * creates new node and fill the given data
 */
struct node * buildNode(int coefficient, int exponent) {
  struct node *ptr = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof (struct node));
  ptr->coefficient = coefficient;
  ptr->exponent = exponent;
  ptr->next = NULL;
  return ptr;
}

/* insert data in decending order - based on exponent value */
void polynomial_insert(struct node ** myNode, int coefficient, int exponent) {
  struct node *lPtr, *pPtr, *qPtr = *myNode;
  lPtr = buildNode(coefficient, exponent);

  /* inserting new node at appropriate position */
  if (*myNode == NULL || (*myNode)->exponent < exponent) {
    *myNode = lPtr;
    (*myNode)->next = qPtr;
    return;
  }

  /* placing new node between two nodes or end of node */
  while (qPtr) {
    pPtr = qPtr;
    qPtr = qPtr->next;
    if (!qPtr) {
      pPtr->next = lPtr;
      break;

    } 
    else if ((exponent < pPtr->exponent) &&       (exponent > qPtr->exponent)){
    lPtr->next = qPtr;
    pPtr->next = lPtr;
    break;
      }
      }
    return;
  }

  /* inserting new node with resultant data into the output list (n1) */
  void polynomial_add(struct node **n1, int coefficient, int exponent) {
    struct node *x = NULL, *temp = *n1;
    if (*n1 == NULL || (*n1)->exponent < exponent) {
      /* adding at the front */
      *n1 = x = buildNode(coefficient, exponent);
      (*n1)->next = temp;
    } else {
      while (temp) {
    if (temp->exponent == exponent) {
      /* updating the co-efficient value  alone */
      temp->coefficient = temp->coefficient + coefficient;
      return;
    }
    if (temp->exponent > exponent && (!temp->next || temp->next->exponent < exponent)) {
      /* inserting in the middle or end */
      x = buildNode(coefficient, exponent);
      x->next = temp->next;
      temp->next = x;
      return;
    }
    temp = temp->next;
      }
      x->next = NULL;
      temp->next = x;
    }
  }

  void polynomial_multiply(struct node **n1, struct node *n2, struct node *n3) {
    struct node * temp;
    int coefficient, exponent;

    temp = n3;

    /* if both input list are absent, then output list is NULL */
    if (!n2 && !n3)
      return;

    /* input list 1(n2) is absent, then output list is input list2 (n3) */
    if (!n2) {
      *n1 = n3;
    } else if (!n3) {

      /*
       * list n3 is absent, then o/p list is n2
       */
      *n1 = n2;
    } else {
      while (n2) {
    while (n3) {
      /* multiply coefficient & add exponents */
      coefficient = n2->coefficient * n3->coefficient;
      exponent = n2->exponent + n3->exponent;
      n3 = n3->next;
      /* insert the above manipulated data to o/p list */
      polynomial_add(n1, coefficient, exponent);
    }
    n3 = temp;
    n2 = n2->next;
      }
    }
    return;
  }

  /* delete the given input list */
  struct node * polynomial_deleteList(struct node *ptr) {
    struct node *temp;
    while (ptr){
      temp = ptr->next;
      free(ptr);
      ptr = temp;
    }
    return NULL;
  }

  void polynomial_view(struct node *ptr) {
    int i = 0;
    int flag=0;
    while (ptr) {
      if(ptr->exponent != 0 || ptr->exponent != 1 ){
    if(ptr->coefficient > 0 && flag==0 ){
      printf("%dx^%d", ptr->coefficient,ptr->exponent);
      flag++;
    }
    else if (ptr->coefficient > 0 && flag==1 )
      printf("+%dx^%d", ptr->coefficient,ptr->exponent);
    else if(ptr->coefficient < 0)
      printf("%dx^%d", ptr->coefficient,ptr->exponent);
      }
      else if (ptr->exponent == 0){
    if(ptr->coefficient > 0 && flag==0 ){
      printf("%d", ptr->coefficient);
      flag++;
    }
    else if (ptr->coefficient > 0 && flag==1 )
      printf("+%d", ptr->coefficient);
    else if(ptr->coefficient < 0)
      printf("%d", ptr->coefficient);
      }
      else if( ptr->exponent == 1 ){
    if(ptr->coefficient > 0 && flag==0 ){
      printf("%dx", ptr->coefficient);
      flag++;
    }
    else if (ptr->coefficient > 0 && flag==1 )
      printf("+%dx", ptr->coefficient);
    else if(ptr->coefficient < 0)
      printf("%dx", ptr->coefficient);
      }
      ptr = ptr->next;
      i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
  }

  int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int coefficient, exponent, i, n;
    int count;
    printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=\n");
    printf("            Multiplication of Two Polynomials\n");
    printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=\n");
    printf("Enter the number of coefficients in the multiplicand:");
    scanf("%d",&count);
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
      printf("Enter the coefficient part:");
      scanf("%d", &coefficient);
      printf("Enter the exponent part:");
      scanf("%d",&exponent);
          polynomial_insert(&hPtr1, coefficient, exponent);
    }
    printf("Enter the number of coefficients in the multiplier:");
    scanf("%d",&count);
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
      printf("Enter the coefficient part:");
      scanf("%d", &coefficient);
      printf("Enter the exponent part:");
      scanf("%d",&exponent);
          polynomial_insert(&hPtr2, coefficient, exponent);
    }
        printf("Polynomial Expression 1: ");
        polynomial_view(hPtr1);
        printf("Polynomial Expression 2: ");
        polynomial_view(hPtr2);

        polynomial_multiply(&hPtr3, hPtr1, hPtr2);

        printf("Output:\n");
        polynomial_view(hPtr3);

    printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
        hPtr1 = polynomial_deleteList(hPtr1);
        hPtr2 = polynomial_deleteList(hPtr2);
        hPtr3 = polynomial_deleteList(hPtr3);

        return 0;
  }
```

The output which I expect is  following

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=–=
Multiplication of Two Polynomials
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=–=
Enter the number of coefficients in the multiplicand:2
Enter the coefficient part:3
Enter the exponent part:2
Enter the coefficient part:2
Enter the exponent part:3
Enter the number of coefficients in the multiplier:2
Enter the coefficient part:4
Enter the exponent part:2
Enter the coefficient part:1
Enter the exponent part:3
Polynomial Expression 1: 2x^3+3x^2
Polynomial Expression 2: 1x^3+4x^2
Output:
2x^6+11x^5+12x^4
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

But instead of that the output which is coming is

```
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=
            Multiplication of Two Polynomials
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=--=
Enter the number of coefficients in the multiplicand:3
Enter the coefficient part:10
Enter the exponent part:x
Enter the coefficient part:Enter the exponent part:Enter the coefficient part:Enter the exponent part:Enter the number of coefficients in the multiplier:Enter the coefficient part:Enter the exponent part:Enter the coefficient part:Enter the exponent part:Enter the coefficient part:Enter the exponent part:Polynomial Expression 1: 10x^0+10x^0+10x^0
Polynomial Expression 2: 10x^0+10x^0+10x^0
Output:
900x^0
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
```

What is the error in code above?

Comment: It's not immediately clear that there is any error *per se* in the code.  You have an error in your **input**, and the program is not robust against that.  In particular, you have entered "x" for the first exponent (which also is not consistent with your expected output, inasmuch as that echoes the program input as well).

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. You can also test each part of the code separately to figure out exactly which part of the code is causing the problem, and make a [mcve]. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. Debugging your own code is an important skill in programming. See http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/.

Answer (score 0):

In the example input, you have given `x` for the exponent part.

```
Enter the exponent part:x
```

The character `x` is read into an `exponent` which is an integer. Read  What is the result of this?
From the C language standard (n1256):

> **7.19.6.4 The scanf function**
>   Synopsis
>   1. #include 
>   int scanf(const char * restrict format, ...);
>   Description
>   2. **The scanf function is equivalent to fscanf** with the argument stdin interposed before the arguments to scanf.
>
> **7.19.6.2 The fscanf function**
>   ...
>
> 10. Except in the case of a % specifier, the input item (or, in the case of a %n directive, the count of input characters) is converted to a type appropriate to the conversion specifier. **If the input item is not a matching sequence, the execution of the directive fails: this condition is a matching failure.** Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a *, the result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.

This will further cause problems in the `polynomial_insert` function.
Before calling the `polynomial_insert` function, you can check if the `scanf` has succeeded and if the values read from std input into `coefficient` and `exponent` variables are in an acceptable range.

See @JonathanLeffler's comment which explains this well.

Comment: I'm not convinced the the `x` yields 'undefined behaviour'.  The input fails and no value is set, and any decisions based on uninitialized variables leads to undefined behaviour, but the simple 'input failed' is not itself undefined behaviour.  It is not spotting that the input failed that leads to dubious, possibly undefined, behaviour.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Edited the answer and added references.

Comment: The `behaviour is undefined` part applies when there is no matching failure, there was no assignment suppression, and the pointer passed to `scanf()` does not have the appropriate type.  A simple matching failure does not inevitably invoke undefined behaviour — though undefined behaviour is likely if the calling code does not spot that there was a matching failure.

Comment: I suggested the OP to check if scanf has succeeded before proceeding further. Anyway, to avoid confusion, I will remove the emphasis in the last part of the quote.

Comment: You have: _The character `x` is read into an `exponent` which is an integer._ . It would be more accurate to say something like "When the character `x` is read while processing what is supposed to be the integer exponent, the conversion fails, leaving the `x` in the input stream for the next input operation.  The matching failure causes the `scanf()` call to stop, reporting the number of successful assignments made prior to the matching failure — which will be zero in this case.  You _must_ check the return value from every `scanf()` so that you can spot and handle matching failures."

Comment: You explained it much better. I will cite your comment in the answer.